# How to make my background image the same on different computers resolution?

Tags: css, frontend

I have set up a background-image for large and medium screens. 
I have a touchbar macbook and it fits perfectly.

If I play with the mouse to make the window smaller (to see how it would be for different resolutions and less pixels), it's completely responsive and looks fine (it cuts a bit the right part of the picture but it's not zooming). 
Same when I open the developer tools, the Ipad pro version is half-cut but not zoomed.

But when I try to go on the website with an older macbook, the image is completely zoomed and does not fit the screen anymore.

I don't understand how there can be such a difference as we have different resolutions but same inches.. And as when I play with it on my computer, the image stays at the right size even with less pixels.

How can I solve this problem? Why is it doing this? I am fine if the image is a bit cut on the right or left side but I don't want it to be zoomed.

I have tried - height: auto, width: 100vw, background-size:contain (but it's too small) and no-repeat... basically everything with css

```
background-image: url(/assets/dessin-ba68b8b….png);
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
```

Thank you

Comment: In what browser do you encounter the issue?

Comment: Google chrome but I tried on Safari and it's the same. I think it's because I have a Retina and pixels are "different". No idea how to handle that. My friend has a 13inches macbook as well so I don't get why it makes such a difference

Answer (score 0):

When you use `cover` for background it is guaranteed that the same image will NOT look perfect on all screen sizes, since the browser needs to display it in different dimensions.

To handle this you may generate several images, each for screen size you aim at and use  [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to apply the appropriate image for each screen size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I understand that, but in this case it is the same size screen. Just different generation computers. And the difference is huge. I am not expecting it to be exactly the same on all size screens, but I don't understand why it is zooming instead of cutting just the left or right part. When I lower the window size on my computer the image looks different and is cut, so that's fine, and I would expect the same behaviour all the time..

Comment: As an update, I just tried to change the image with media queries depending on the screen size, but still the same problem (which makes sense as we both are 13,3 inches...)

Comment: I think it's because I have a Retina screen.